# How to implement following with Zend navigation?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a top navigation and a side one

```
Home | Tours  | Booking

Tour1
------
Tour2
------
Tour3
```

I show the side menu depending on a active top item.
But sometimes when the side menu item is clicked I have to show that items children instead of the sidemenu. When no children exist I just show Children of a top menu depending on the active item.
I an really having difficulties implementing that kind a logic and any help would be appreciated.

//Comment button is not working so I will add comments here
After stumbling the zend navigation view helpers, I am coming to the point -
Understanding the concept of how in zend V part of MVC is implemented can save someone who is new to the framework many hours. 
As said in the answer to this question - "Use what is available", thought first we have to know where to find what is already available out there - that is where comes handy to take a look at the concept of helpers and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out examples [#34 - 44](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html), specifically #36.

Comment: thanks probably you right just using a existent view helper should solve it. First I was kind a rendering two different menus but faced a difficulty to distinguish which is child of which branch and so on... thanks

Comment: I try to make it a habit of using what is available in the Framework already.  There's no point in reinventing the wheel.

One of the better documented components in the Framework is Zend_Navigation, and it is extremely flexible.  Almost every scenario I've ever needed, can be found in what already exists.